# Getting error while connecting to the amadeus api

Tags: rest, postman, soap-client, amadeus, soapheader

I was trying to send request to amadeus server through postman.
i puted all requried credentials in header but it still giving me error as header is incorrect.

I puted SOAPAction inside header.

and i generating the request structre through WSDL file given by amadeus.

This is my request structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageID>1e98f38c-db15-4d57-8de5-490c31d5a3</MessageID>
        <Action>http://webservices.amadeus.com/FLIREQ_07_1_1A</Action>
        <To>https://nodeD2.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWAFSDAFAF</To>
        <Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                <Username>WSASDDFACS</Username>
                <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsssoap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">c2VjcmV0bm9uY2reUx==</Nonce>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">2@@2HGDFFDF</Password>
                <oas1:Created>2023-09-20T11:23:013Z</oas1:Created>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
        <AMA_SecurityHostedUser xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1">
            <UserID AgentDutyCode="SU" RequestorType="U" PseudoCityCode="PDX1SFD2405"
POS_Type="1"/>
        </AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
        <Session TransactionStatusCode="Start">
    </Session>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <Air_FlightInfo xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FLIREQ_07_1_1A" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.amadeus.com/FLIREQ_07_1_1A schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <generalFlightInfo>
                <flightDate>
                    <departureDate>ABCDEF</departureDate>
                    <arrivalDate>ABCDEF</arrivalDate>
                    <dateVariation>A</dateVariation>
                </flightDate>
                <boardPointDetails>
                    <trueLocationId>ABC</trueLocationId>
                </boardPointDetails>
                <offPointDetails>
                    <trueLocationId>ABCD</trueLocationId>
                </offPointDetails>
                <companyDetails>
                    <marketingCompany>A</marketingCompany>
                    <operatingCompany>A</operatingCompany>
                </companyDetails>
                <flightIdentification>
                    <flightNumber>A</flightNumber>
                    <operationalSuffix>A</operationalSuffix>
                </flightIdentification>
                <flightTypeDetails>
                    <flightIndicator>string</flightIndicator>
                    <flightIndicator>string</flightIndicator>
                </flightTypeDetails>
                <marriageDetails>
                    <relation>AB</relation>
                    <lineNumber>-639609.765094196</lineNumber>
                </marriageDetails>
                <marriageDetails>
                    <marriageIdentifier>1496560.2349058</marriageIdentifier>
                    <otherRelation>A</otherRelation>
                    <carrierCode>AB</carrierCode>
                </marriageDetails>
                <marriageDetails>
                    <lineNumber>1253760.2349058</lineNumber>
                    <otherRelation>AB</otherRelation>
                </marriageDetails>
            </generalFlightInfo>
        </Air_FlightInfo>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this is response what i'm getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring> 12|Presentation|soap message header incorrect</faultstring>
            <faultactor>SI:muxDZ1</faultactor>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I go through all github and stackoverflow questions but didn't work any approach.

I was trying to implement amadeus soap apis.
and I'm expecting that request works properly and gives me correct response.

Comment: Please kindly raise the concerns to your dedicated Amadeus team, this stackoverflow amadus tag is for Self-Service APIs only which is publicly available.

Comment: yes, I initiated a thread with them.  okay, it will help others so I still kept this question here.